# How to connect webhook in our spring boot application when docusign connect webhook?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi, webhooks

I configured docusign connect as webhook. if recipient sign the document, i can get a webhook calls. But want to connect webhook in to my spring boot application and when webhook get call, i need to get a response in my spring boot app? Is it possible ?
In below link architecture it showing we can connect it into spring boot

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/

It's telling if you have subscribed to triggered event, sends a webhook call back message.
I need to know how to get response in m spring boot app when webhook get a call

Answer (score 1):

With webhooks, your application is the `server` for the incoming POST requests from the client (DocuSign in this case). So you need to configure your application as a server, available on the public internet with a URL address that starts with https://foo.woof.etc

Alternatively, create the server using AWS Lambda functions or equivalent, and then your application can make outgoing GET requests to see if a webhook notification has been received or not. See this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4) for more.